# Google Calendar(Android) edit event - what is UI pattern?

Tags: android, user-interface, design-patterns, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created mobile app for android(with Xamarin Forms). Now I do not like the look of it, I want to update it. I like the look of the app Google Calendar. It is true material design(I read a lot about it). I like how to add and edit events in calendar. For example this:

[image]

The edit button, the data ratio and the picture above - are excellent.  I want to do the same.
  What is the name of this pattern? I read a lot about material design but I did not find article about this solution(pattern).

How it's called? What can I read guide(about this pattern edit)?

Comment: If you want to know how to achieve this layout in xamarin android or in XF, we can give a help on that. But sorry, I don't know what is the design pattern here and seems I can't find guide for it.

Comment: Yes, please help me how create this layout in xamarin forms.